# pythonで[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python': 'python'と表示されることの解決策を教えてください。

Tags: python, python3, 機械学習

以下のpython scriptを回そうとした時に表題のエラー「[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python'」が出力されます。
解決法がわからないので教えてください。

実行しているものとしては、wikipediaで学習したBERTを作成しようとしており、その事前学習段階を行おうとしています。
ターミナルから実行するのでは、入力内容が多いため、以下のpython scriptを作成し、実行することで自動的に事前学習が行われることを想定しています。

実行環境としてはnvidia-dockerを使用し、コンテナのベースはubuntu18.04。そこにpythonなどなどをインストールしてコンテナ内で実行しようとしている形になります。
tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0

```
import tensorflow as tf
import subprocess

print(tf.__version__)

input_data_gcs = '/work/data'

target_dirs = [
    'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH', 'AI', 'AJ', 'AK', 'AL', 'AM', 'AN',
    'AO', 'AP', 'AQ', 'AR', 'AS', 'AT', 'AU', 'AV', 'AW', 'AX', 'AY', 'AZ', 'BA', 'BB',
    'BC', 'BD', 'BE'
]

max_seq_len = 512

input_file = ','.join(['{}/wiki/{}/all_maxseq{}.tfrecord'.format(input_data_gcs, elem, max_seq_len) for elem in target_dirs])

output_gcs = '/work/model'

cmd = ('python '
       './src/run_pretraining.py '
       '--input_file={} '
       '--output_dir={} '
       '--do_train=True '
       '--do_eval=True '
       '--train_batch_size=64 '
       '--max_seq_length={} '
       '--max_predictions_per_seq=20 '
       '--num_train_steps=1400000 '
       '--num_warmup_steps=10000 '
       '--save_checkpoints_steps=10000 '
       '--learning_rate=1e-4'
       .format(input_file, output_gcs, max_seq_len))
subprocess.run(cmd.split())
```

このコードを使用すると以下のエラーが出力され、処理が進まない現状です。

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python': 'python'
```

どなたかご回答よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

`python3`タグでの質問ですので、
`apt install python3`でPythonをインストールしたと仮定します。

その場合`python`コマンドではなく`python3`コマンドを使う必要があります。